# child_process could not be found within the project-- react native

Tags: npm, react-native, node-modules, mobile-application

Created a new project on react native 0.61.4
Copied the screens and functionality from previous project which was on 0.55.4.
Everything is build but the bundling is failed with the following errors:

**error: bundling failed: Error: Unable to resolve module `child_process` from `node_modules\jest-changed-files\node_modules\execa\index.js`: child_process could not be found within the project.**

[Error: Bundling failed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PFGiW.png)

Package.json:

```
{

  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint ."
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "execa": "^3.2.0",
    "jest-changed-files": "^24.9.0",
    "mockjs": "^1.1.0",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "native-base": "^2.13.8",
    "react": "16.9.0",
    "react-moment": "^0.9.6",
    "react-month-picker": "^1.3.11",
    "react-native": "0.61.4",
    "react-native-datepicker-dialog": "0.0.9",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.5.0",
    "react-native-image-slider-show": "^1.0.3",
    "react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "^0.9.1",
    "react-native-linear-gradient": "^2.5.6",
    "react-native-modal-datetime-picker": "^7.6.0",
    "react-native-month-selector": "^1.4.0",
    "react-native-responsive-screen": "^1.3.0",
    "react-native-simple-table": "0.0.3",
    "react-native-slideshow": "^1.0.1",
    "react-native-spinkit": "^1.5.0",
    "react-native-svg": "^9.13.3",
    "react-native-swipe-gestures": "^1.0.4",
    "react-navigation": "^4.0.10",
    "react-navigation-stack": "^1.10.3",
    "react-time-picker": "^3.7.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.6.4",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.6.3",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^0.0.5",
    "babel-jest": "^24.9.0",
    "eslint": "^6.6.0",
    "jest": "^24.9.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.57.0",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.9.0"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  },
  "browser": { "child_process": false }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Please clean your project then run project.Some library is not adding by autolinking fearure so please check and add properly like firebase library need to add manually.I attached some screenshot so please check.[image: for add dependency manually]

[image: add class path properly]

Answer (score 0):

[image]
Check in any of the files you were working on recently and be sure you are not mistakenly importing `child_process` somewhere. In my case it was `process` as shown in the image above.